# Redirect all /*.html or /*/*.html to home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, nginx, server, unicorn

I had a website which had URLs link /page1.html or /category/category-page.html. Now this site is moved to `Rails` application and it has restful routes. I'm using `unicorn` as app server. I want to redirect all type of above URLs to home page of my new application. I'm having following configurations currently. Please help me write configurations.

```
upstream unicorn {
 server unix:/tmp/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /srv/www/example/current/public;


  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.access.log;
  keepalive_timeout 5;


  location / {
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri/index.htm @unicorn;
  }

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;


    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn;
      break;
    }
  }

 location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    deny all;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  location = /500.html {
    root /var/www/example/current/public;
  }

}
```